# How to remove Google font Roboto from head in Nuxt/Vuetify?

Tags: fonts, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

By default Vuetify includes Google font "Roboto" in the head of the static generated page from Nuxt. How I can remove this font from the head? Is there an option for this? I would like to save this unnecessary request...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you are using Nuxt + vuetify , do these:

1. install "@nuxtjs/vuetify" package.
2. In the nuxt.config file add these config:

```js
buildModules: [
  '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
],
```

```js
      vuetify: {
        customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'], // vuetify var styles.
        optionsPath: './vuetify.options.js', // vuetify option like theme.
        defaultAssets: false,
        treeShake: true
      }
```

> When you add defaultAssets: **false**, it delete the builtin font & its request. then you can add your font locally.

more detail link:
[defaultAssets](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#defaultassets)

Comment: Great! "defaultAssets: false" done the thing - thanks for the tip!

Comment: When I do this, it removes the mdi icons. How can I add them back in?

Comment: @connorcode , you need to define it as an object:
      defaultAssets: {
        font: false,
        icons: true,
      },
or add mdi-icons manually vuetify docs explain this well.

Comment: This removes the menu and expand icons (nav) but maintains the social media icons, very strange

Comment: @connorcode are you using version v2.0.0-beta.2 of vuetify module? cuz its not stable yet , you must use v1.11 .