# How to improve page speed with roboto font in vuetify plugin with nuxt

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js, lighthouse

when I'm doing a lighthous report, this performance issue appers `Eliminate render-blocking resources` from a url `/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap`
it was generated by vuetify framework with nuxt, how can I not block this rendering?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Can you please mention the codes as well. Are you trying to import this external css file?

Comment: the code is on github https://github.com/Renato66/Renato66.github.io
well, im not importing it at all, but im using it on my page lighthouse: https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com//lh/html?url=https%3A%2F%2Frenato66.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `vuetify` adds *Roboto* fonts and *MDI* icons to your project, loading it externally from a synchronous scrip in the HEAD. It causes your project to load them before everything else, taking around 1 second delay for your pages to load.

You can turn-off that by adding the following to your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
vuetify: {
    defaultAssets: false
}
```

Source: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983551/how-to-remove-google-font-roboto-from-head-in-nuxt-vuetify) on Stackoverflow.